# Scroll per 100vh or section

Tags: javascript, scroll, viewport

I'm currently working on a website and I thought that it would be nice to animate some stuff with javascript. The only problem is that I never really worked with it before.

I got this single page website that's made up of sections. Every section is surrounded by a div. All these divs have the same class and all these divs have the same height of 100vh (the height of the viewport). I want visitors to be able scroll per 100vh / section.

While googling, I stumbled apon this tutorial / code:

https://codepen.io/Javarome/post/full-page-sliding

```js
function ScrollHandler(pageId) {
  var page = $('#' + pageId); 
  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    // Do something with page
  });
}
new ScrollHandler('one'); 
new ScrollHandler('two');
new ScrollHandler('three');
```

The problem is that this tutorial is focussing on sections with different ID's. Is it possible for me to edit this code so that it works with sections with the same class? And if so, how? Keep in mind that I'm a total javascript noob.

If there are any other ways to achieve the same result, feel free to tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47134880/5452965), it might be useful for you

Comment: This works perfectly, although it stops my anchor links from working. Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: What do you mean by _"although it stops my anchor links from working"_. Post some code mate and try to explain what is the scenario, because if it's not clear people can't help you :)

Comment: I'm sorry. What I mean is, I have a navigation bar with anchor links to some of the sections. With the script you provided I can't, doe example, go from the home section (first section) straight to the contact section (last section) by clicking the navigation bar. The navigation bar is just an unordered list with simple html hyperlinks to id's.

Comment: Well yes, the script that I gave you doesn't take care for such a scenario, it just takes care for the scrolling. This is additional code that should be implemented - _"Navigating to section"_

Comment: I figured. I know you're probably busy, but could you perhaps give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Well I guess there could be variety of ways to do it, but something that comes in y mind now is to listen for [**hashchange**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event -> prevent default behavior -> find the element depending on the hash and smoothly scroll to it

Comment: I found a script that's making it possible to scroll smoothly to anchors. The only thing that I still need is to prevent the default behaviour of the script you provided. Do these scripts need to be combined in one to actually be able to prevent the default behaviour? And how do I actually prevent the behaviour. Once again, I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Well no worries mate, but I can't imagine exactly the case. If you do actual example with your code - jsfiddle, plunkr, codepen something ... I can have a look there

Comment: I hope this works, I'm still new to this https://jsfiddle.net/bnnughn0/

Comment: Add also your HTML and CSS, the whole snippet that you are working with, because right now there is just a piece of javascript that is doing nothing :)

Comment: Right. 2nd attempt. I added the html and css code that matters and also added your script to it (not in the right way probably, but I think it should be clear enough). Let me know if you need anything else. https://jsfiddle.net/bnnughn0/2/

Comment: [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/zLaLosk5/2/) is the code buddy, but it is super ugly because I'm in a big hurry, please take some time to understand it and make it better. One day I will make it better once I have some time. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working like a charm right now :)